# seaborn countplot add xtick this is sum of all other xtick values

Tags: seaborn

I'm trying to plot a seaborn countplot with parameter x and hue:

```
data = {"group1":[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2], "group2":["A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
sns.countplot(data=df, x="group1", hue="group2")
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

I want to add another X ticks in the same graph, summerizng values acorss all other xticks (A value would be 4, B value would be 3, C value would be 3).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find an elegantly looking solution to your request, but have only come to this yet:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {"group1":[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
        "group2":["A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

g1 = sns.countplot(data=df, x="group1", hue="group2")

count_labels = np.repeat(df["group2"].value_counts().values,  # repeat group2 category counts
                         3)  # for number of group1 categories/x-ticks

g2 = g1.twiny()  # add twin axes with shared y-axis

g2.set_xticks([p.get_x() for p in g1.patches])  # place ticks at where g1 bars are
g2.set_xticklabels(count_labels)  # assign tick labels
g2.set_xlabel("group2 category count")
g2.xaxis.set_ticks_position("bottom")
g2.xaxis.set_label_position("bottom")
g2.spines["bottom"].set_position(("axes", -0.2))
g2.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
plt.tick_params(which="both", top=False)
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

So I thought you might rather want to annotate the bars:

```py
for p, label in zip(g1.patches, count_labels):
    g1.annotate(label, (p.get_x()+0.1, 0.1))
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

In case you want to use subplots:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
g1 = sns.countplot(data=df, x="group1", hue="group2", ax=axes[0])
g2 = sns.countplot(data=df, x="group2", ax=axes[1])
```

This would look this way:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I need the data summrizng all the bars to be visual.
I thought maybe I would use plt.subplots and plot them together. But how do I create a simple bar by stacking the x values?

Comment: Do you mean you want to stack the bars on top of one another on a different subplot? So it would be like 3 bars, `A:4, B:3, C:3`? Describe the desired plot some more, please. Anyways, there's always an option to group and aggregate the data and use it as an input for another subplot.

Comment: I mean exactly what you described

Comment: @Luis_12345 alright, I edited my answer to add the subplots option.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to make the bottom plot stacked? it is easy for the top plot (beacuse of the hue), but I havn't find an option to make the bottom as a single stacked bar (which will add up to a count of 10 and consist blue, orange and green parts.

Comment: @Luis_12345 `seaborn` doesn't really play well with stacked bars, so here's a `pandas` workaround: `df.groupby('group2').agg('count').T.plot.bar(stacked=True)`